# Import data from SQL Server restricted by date to an Excel worksheet

Tags: sql-server, database, excel, excel-2010

I have been working in a worksheet from another guy, and I'm having some trouble. The worksheet is importing all data from the table on SQL server, and now it has about 200MB.

The problem: I only want to retrieve data from a respective month **and** year.

Configuration:

```
Excel 2010:
- Connection Properties -> Definition -> Command Type: Table
-           "                  "         Command Text: "Database"."dbo"."Table"
```

How can I put a "where" clause in this command text to restrict date like month "03" and year "2013"? Or, what should I do to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: You have to give your table definition and columns...

Answer (score 1):

Using command type `Table` loads all rows from the table; you need to change the command type to `SQL`, then you can use any SQL query you like, e.g.:

```
select * from MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable 
where YearNumber = 2013 and MonthNumber = 3
```